# Need an ideal way to handle tab bar in app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to create an app where there is a login screen, and when user logs in open up home page with tab bar controller.

I have created a single view application and have created login screen, home screen and a tab bar on it.

In tab bar delegate, I am adding screens to tab bar by [self.view addSubView firstView.view]

My problem is if I open up 4th tab, and switch to 2nd tab and I have to go back to home screen, so I press home btw on nav bar, it shows view 4 which is already on stack of uiviews.

How do I switch between all tab bar views and add navigation to them ? Which ideal method is to be used?

Comment: can you share a snapshot of your application for better understanding ?
I am not getting you clearly, is it that after you login, you show home screen with empty tabbar and when you tap on say, 1st Tab, you show the first tab. (i.e. after login you just show the tabbar but not any tab of that tabbar)

Comment: Ok, I will explain it here as I can't put the screenshots. I launch the app -> login page ->login page has forgot pwd and back btn to login page -> after login open home screen with tab bar -> tabs have navigation as well. Please help me in building up the architechture. Whether it should be tabbased app or single view app? And how to approach for this kind of architechture?

Comment: so after login you want to see the home screen and the tab bar but no tabs should be selected....rite ?
you could use the single view-based approach and load the home screen after you login with a tab bar at the bottom.

Comment: have u added a different button(HomeButton) on your navBar ? also where did you add the navBar ?
one more question is, if you have added the HomeButton, then what are you doin in that button, i mean are you performing removefromSuperView or what?

Answer (score 1):

I've created app that is doing what you need (I guess). You can find it in app store for iphone using name Torchoo. It is free and there is test account so you can see how it works and if its really what you need. If yes, ping me here I will show you the sources and how I did it.

In couple of words, you need normal tabbar controller that has number of navigation controllers and each of them has number of view controllers. And login screen is just a modal view that shows/hides when you need it. Most of things may be done in storyboard.

Comment: Ok, I will explain it here as I can't put the screenshots. I launch the app -> login page ->login page has forgot pwd and back btn to login page -> after login open home screen with tab bar -> tabs have navigation as well. Please help me in building up the architechture. Whether it should be tabbased app or single view app? And how to approach for this kind of architechture?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it actually but i think you want to attach all the view by navigation controller.

But it's useless. if you want to use navigation bar then it ll navigate in another view but tabbar will give you different views on every tab.

so, first see the use of both of them then ask....

Comment: Ok, I will explain it here as I can't put the screenshots. I launch the app -> login page ->login page has forgot pwd and back btn to login page -> after login open home screen with tab bar -> tabs have navigation as well. Please help me in building up the architechture. Whether it should be tabbased app or single view app? And how to approach for this kind of architechture?

Comment: I think i got you. You need Navigation App. in that app first page will be login page -> then Main home page -> custom Tab bar in this home page -> you can use different views in tab bar and in perticular tab you will navigate in different views..... after log out you will reach at your first page (login page).